# How to use "load_model" in Keras after trained using as metric "tf.keras.metrics.AUC"?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, metrics, auc

After training using that metric on my `model.fit()`. When I try to load the model using "load_model". It don't recognize the metric AUC, so I add it on `custom_objects={"auc":AUC}`.

I get this error:

> ValueError: Unknown metric function: {'class_name': 'AUC' ...
> returning all the thresholds used and more information about the metric.

The code:

```
model.compile(..., metrics=["accuracy", AUC(name="auc", curve="PR")]
load_model(checkpoint, custom_objects={"auc":AUC(name="auc")})
```

Comment: It tried saving a model with the `AUC` metric and I could load the model without mentioning it in `custom_objects`. Which TF version are you using?

Comment: tf 1.15 - keras 2.3.1

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. When you have no defined metrics, you can load the model without compiling it. Just set `compile=False` like this:

```
model.compile(..., metrics=["accuracy", AUC(name="auc", curve="PR")]
load_model(checkpoint, custom_objects={"auc": AUC(name="auc")}, compile=False)
```